# Vendor lock-in when trying to migrate an EC2 wordpress website that serves via cloudfront and stores on an S3 bucket

Tags: wordpress, server, migration, amazon-aws, amazon-cloudfront

I was wondering if I have a wordpress website on EC2 instance and it is saving everything on an S3 bucket and serves via cloudfront..

If I want to move my website one day to some other hosting, will I see issues there?

Someone told me that AWS somehow TRAPS their customers into using AWS and then the prices skyrocket. That is what he told me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is, of-course, an element of vendor lockin, but as you are using wordpress you should be able to re-engineer the parts of your platform that rely on S3 fairly easily  (Moving the EC2 instance elsewhere is unlikely to provide additional challenges over any other migration, and most software that supports S3 supports other storage systems as well).

I put to you that, at the scale where EC2/S3 becomes meaningfully excessive, the costs of migration become relatively unimportant.  While I am no fan of AWS and dont agree, a lot of large enties use it to store huge amounts of data and they argue it saves them money once the hidden costs of running at-scale are factored in.

Comment: wow thank you so much for the answer.... I am so tired of these online forums immediately locking my question or telling me to improve my grammar or telling me wrong forum or replying but just diverting away from the crux of the matter and now providing any meaningful answer. I find it... it is really hard to learn things online these days, despite so many forums and websites. I don't know why. I am definitely not a stupid person since I studied medicine and had great grades in school. I definitely can learn things easily. But it's hard to find quick simple direct answers like this. Thank you